# How many minimum datasets for k = 10/5 on kFold cross validation?

Tags: python, numpy, dataset, classification, cross-validation

I want to ask, I'm doing a character classification with 20 classes, and a dataset of 1800 (64x64 size)

I use kfold cross validation, and get high accuracy, but the validation result is low (only reaches 50), I use the sigmoid activation function, and my output layer uses softmax

I also use 3 hidden layers, with each node 128,64,32.

how can my validation improve?

here is my code:

```
#Model NN
class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self):

        self.lr = 0.0001

        self.w1 = np.random.randn(jum_pixel, num_w1)
        self.b1 = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=0.1, size=(1, num_w1))

        self.w2 = np.random.randn(num_w1, num_w2)
        self.b2 = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=0.1, size=(1, num_w2))

        self.w3 = np.random.randn(num_w2, num_w3)
        self.b3 = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=0.1, size=(1, num_w3))

        self.w4 = np.random.randn(num_w3, class_label)
        self.b4 = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=0.1, size=(1, class_label))

    def feedforward(self):
        z1 = np.dot(self.x, self.w1) + self.b1
        self.a1 = sigmoid(z1)

        z2 = np.dot(self.a1, self.w2) + self.b2
        self.a2 = sigmoid(z2)

        z3 = np.dot(self.a2, self.w3) + self.b3
        self.a3 = sigmoid(z3)

        z4 = np.dot(self.a3, self.w4) + self.b4
        self.a4 = softmax(z4)

    def backprop(self):

        output_errors = self.a4 - self.y #turunan loss loglikelihood terhadap softmax

        error_h3 = np.dot(output_errors, self.w4.T) #error hidden 3
        Eh3_dsigmoid = error_h3 * dsigmoid(self.a3)  # EH3dsigmoid

        error_h2 = np.dot(error_h3, self.w3.T) #error hidden 2
        Eh2_dsigmoid = error_h2 * dsigmoid(self.a2)  # EH2dsigmoid

        error_h1 = np.dot(error_h2, self.w2.T) #error hidden 1
        Eh1_dsigmoid = error_h1 * dsigmoid(self.a1)  # EH1dsigmoid

        self.w4 -= self.lr * np.dot(self.a3.T, output_errors)
        self.b4 -= self.lr * np.sum(output_errors, axis=0, keepdims=True)

        self.w3 -= self.lr * np.dot(self.a2.T, Eh3_dsigmoid)
        self.b3 -= self.lr * np.sum(Eh3_dsigmoid, axis=0, keepdims=True)

        self.w2 -= self.lr * np.dot(self.a1.T, Eh2_dsigmoid)
        self.b2 -= self.lr * np.sum(Eh2_dsigmoid, axis=0, keepdims=True)

        self.w1 -= self.lr * np.dot(self.x.T, Eh1_dsigmoid)
        self.b1 -= self.lr * np.sum(Eh1_dsigmoid, axis=0, keepdims=True)

    def train(self, x, y):

        self.x = np.array(x, ndmin=2)
        self.y = np.array(y, ndmin=2)
        self.feedforward()
        self.backprop()

    def predict(self, data):
        self.x = np.array(data, ndmin=2)
        self.feedforward()
        return self.a4

    def evaluate(self, x, y):
        corrects, wrongs = 0, 0
        for i in range(len(x)):
            res = self.predict(x.iloc[i])
            res_max = res.argmax()
            if res_max == y[i]:
                corrects += 1
            else:
                wrongs += 1
        return corrects, wrongs
```

```
#Train
akurat_train = []
akurat_val = []
total_train = []
total_val = []
mean_valid = []
mean_train = []
count = 0
kf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, random_state=None, shuffle=True)
for train_index, valid_index in kf.split(x, train_label):
    model = NeuralNetwork()
    epochs = 1500
    x_train, x_valid = x.iloc[train_index], x.iloc[valid_index]
    y_train, y_valid = train_label[train_index], train_label[valid_index]
    y_train_one_hot, y_test_one_hot = train_labels_one_hot[train_index], train_labels_one_hot[valid_index]
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        print("epoch: ", epoch + 1)
        for i in range(len(x_train)):
            model.train(x_train.iloc[i], y_train_one_hot[i])

        corrects, wrongs = model.evaluate(x_train, y_train)
        akurasi_train = np.around(corrects / (corrects + wrongs), decimals=3)* 100
        print("Training Accruracy: ", akurasi_train, "%")

        corrects, wrongs = model.evaluate(x_valid, y_valid)
        akurasi_val = np.around(corrects / (corrects + wrongs), decimals=3)* 100
        print("Validation Accruracy: ", akurasi_val, "%")
```

Is something wrong with my code?

Comment: Check the class distribution and use augmentations (which makes sense)

Comment: class distribution is appropriate because I use StratifiedKFold

how to do a good augmentation?